# Adapter overrides button onclicklistener

Tags: android, position, adapter, onclicklistener

I'm trying to create a list where each element on that list has 6 buttons. When I'm at second position of that list, the buttons that I set OnClickListener are overriding the functionality of the buttons of the 1st position.

I implemented the getView function in the adapter like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder mViewHolder = null;
    System.out.println("position: "+position);

    if (convertView == null) {

        mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_card_query, parent, false);

        mViewHolder.buttons[0] = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mViewHolder.buttons[1] = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        mViewHolder.buttons[2] = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        mViewHolder.buttons[3] = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button4);
        mViewHolder.buttons[4] = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button5);
        mViewHolder.buttons[5] = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button6);

        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);

    }else{

        mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    int j;
    if(cant<=6) j=cant;
    else if(getCount()-1!=position)j=6*position+6;
        else j=cant;

    System.out.println("Caso: "+6*position+" "+j);
    for(int i=6*position;i<j;i++){
        System.out.println("Bank: "+data.get(i).mID+" "+data.get(i).mDicName);
        mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        if(data.get(i).mDicName.equals("Mercantil")) {
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bank_mercantil);
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setText(data.get(i).mName);
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            //button.setHint(Integer.toString(data.get(i).mID));
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setHint(Integer.toString(i));
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(inflater.getContext(), Advertisement.class);
                    //i.putExtra("id", ((Button) v).getHint().toString());
                    i.putExtra("id", Integer.toString(data.get(Integer.parseInt(((Button) v).getHint().toString())).mID));
                    i.putExtra("name", data.get(Integer.parseInt(((Button) v).getHint().toString())).mName);
                    i.putExtra("bank", BanksInfo.MERCANTIL);
                    inflater.getContext().startActivity(i);
                }

            });
        }
        if(data.get(i).mDicName.equals("Venezuela")) {
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bank_venezuela);
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setText(data.get(i).mName);
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            //button.setHint(Integer.toString(data.get(i).mID));
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setHint(Integer.toString(i));
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(inflater.getContext(), Advertisement.class);
                    //i.putExtra("id", ((Button) v).getHint().toString());
                    i.putExtra("id", Integer.toString(data.get(Integer.parseInt(((Button) v).getHint().toString())).mID));
                    i.putExtra("name", data.get(Integer.parseInt(((Button) v).getHint().toString())).mName);
                    i.putExtra("bank", BanksInfo.VENEZUELA);
                    inflater.getContext().startActivity(i);
                }

            });
        }
        if(data.get(i).mDicName.equals("Provincial")) {
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bank_bbva);
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setTextColor(convertView.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setText(data.get(i).mName);
            //button.setHint(Integer.toString(data.get(i).mID));
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setHint(Integer.toString(i));
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(inflater.getContext(), Advertisement.class);
                    //i.putExtra("id", ((Button) v).getHint().toString());
                    i.putExtra("id", Integer.toString(data.get(Integer.parseInt(((Button) v).getHint().toString())).mID));
                    i.putExtra("name", data.get(Integer.parseInt(((Button) v).getHint().toString())).mName);
                    i.putExtra("bank", BanksInfo.BBVA);
                    inflater.getContext().startActivity(i);
                }

            });
        }
        if(data.get(i).mDicName.equals("Commerce")) {
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bank_commerce);
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setTextColor(convertView.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setText(data.get(i).mName);
            //button.setHint(Integer.toString(data.get(i).mID));
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setHint(Integer.toString(i));
            mViewHolder.buttons[i%6].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(inflater.getContext(), Advertisement.class);
                    //i.putExtra("id", ((Button) v).getHint().toString());
                    i.putExtra("id", Integer.toString(data.get(Integer.parseInt(((Button) v).getHint().toString())).mID));
                    i.putExtra("name", data.get(Integer.parseInt(((Button) v).getHint().toString())).mName);
                    i.putExtra("bank", BanksInfo.COMMERCE);
                    inflater.getContext().startActivity(i);
                }

            });
        }
    }

    if(getCount()-1==position)
        if(cant%6!=0){
            for(int i=(cant%6);i<6;i++){
                mViewHolder.buttons[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.extra);
                mViewHolder.buttons[i].setText("");
                mViewHolder.buttons[i].setHint("");
                mViewHolder.buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    return convertView;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: the code is messy, i cant figure out wats wrong. you should better debug it to find whats going wrong :-/

Comment: The problem is when I set the OnClickListener on the second position, they're overriding the first button, but the drawable background is showing ok. It's messy because is a screen with match_parent on width and height, it's a grid of 3x2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never ever attach onClicklistener in `getView`. Instead use:

```
yourGridView.setOnItemClickListener(..
```

That's because `getView` reuses old views and their on click methods. So after some scrolling your image views are correct but your on click methods are totally messed up and could be behind every image! Hope it helps.

Comment: I was thinking about that but I'm using [this library](https://github.com/alexvasilkov/FoldableLayout) and it doesn't have setOnItemClickListener

Comment: what is your Motivation to use this libary? I would recommend you to start a new question specific on this libary.. and please mark this answere as accepted as it provides the solution for your Problem @SebMek

Comment: * as it provides the solution for your orginal Problem which you have asked for.. @SebMek

Comment: I have to develop an app that has a folding animation on lists. It's the best library that I've found.

Comment: Can't help you with that. I never worked with that libary but i'm sure there are People in this community who know that libary..